# How to get rid of ^H when using webpack with iex -S mix phoenix.server?

Tags: elixir, webpack, phoenix-framework

I use webpack with phoenix. Many `^H` will be output when I use `iex -S mix phoenix.server` to start the server. Like this

```
iex(1)> ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H  0% compile
^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H 10% 
0/1 build modules^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H 70% 
1/1 build modules^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H 40% 
1/2 build modules^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H 30% 
1/3 build modules[bootstrap-sass-loader]: styleLoader: style-loader!
css-loader!sass-loader
...
```

What's the problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 9):

It's because I use `--progress` in the my phoenix watchers config:

```
watchers: [node: ["node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js", "--watch", "--colors",
  "--progress"]]
```

Then webpack will output `\b` to make a progress as the code shows https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/convert-argv.js#L408.

Finally, my solution is changing the webpack arguments to support both `mix phoenix` and `iex -S mix phoenix.server`:

```
webpack_args = ["node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js", "--watch", "--colors",
  "--progress"]
# Remove progress argument to make iex display log normally
if IEx.started?, do: webpack_args = List.delete(webpack_args, "--progress")

config :sample, Sample.Endpoint,
  # ...
  watchers: [node: webpack_args]
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this output is the webpack `--progress` flag, as @tony-han points out correctly, which is configured as a watcher and started for the Phoenix endpoint in `dev` environment.

This and other watchers are run only, if the option `:server` is activated. At least in recent Phoenix versions this setting is set to `false` by default, and it's only activated by the `mix phx.server` task. That means by default this shouldn't happen in `iex` at all.

You can check your `dev` environment's endpoint configuration for a setting `server: true`, which is unnecessary. If you remove it, this problem should be resolved.

NB, the `server: true` setting (or alternatively the more global `config :phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true`) should given in `prod` environment, as this is often started by running a release.